# Is it possible to open a second application in multi task split view?

Tags: ios, swift

We have 2 Apps, that are iPad only.

It's possible for the user to create a multi-tasked application by doing some complicated gestures, described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582) .

I can open a second application using [UIApplication.open](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open). Is it possible to request the OS opens the second app directly in the multi-tasked split view mode?

Comment: I've deleted my comment because it doesn't matter. Short answer? NO. It's how Apple implements sandboxing. Period. And I sincerely doubt that - even if they are iPadOS only - they would accept this. I'm doing something that *may* be similar, and the answer I have is (1) let the user open multiple windows/scenes of the app, (2) add metadata to the drag between them and (3) detect in the drop if it's from the dragged app. Are you trying to do something that doesn't use drag and drop?

Comment: One more thought - are you seeing what changes are in iPadOS 15 beta? It may matter.

Comment: Well there are some sandboxing exceptions, like the usages of app groups. To answer your questions though not doing anything related to drag and drop. I have a scenario where a user just needs to view both apps at once, and putting them into that mode is easier than trying to explain multi-task gestures. 

I did not review the iPadOS 15 Beta though since I would need this compatible with older versions